# US Keyboard with nordic layout in Windows

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I physically have a US keyboard, but I write with a Nordic layout (specifically Danish, changed in Windows 10). I do a lot of programming and the less and greater sign < > are very frequently used. I wonder how to type those symbol with the Nordic layout on a US keyboard. I tried every key :P

[image: Picture of the keyboard]

Comment: https://www.branah.com/danish shows like its just near left shift.

Comment: Yes but US keyboard dont have a key near shift, so I wonder where I press instead

Comment: On my macbook pro its the key with norma \ and shift |. Tried it on https://www.branah.com/danish and it worked fine for < and >.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a mac :/

Comment: Can you put a pic of your keyboard ? Which keys do you use for **\** and **|** ?

Comment: I have updated the post with a picture :)

Comment: Its your key on top of Enter :)

Comment: Note that it is nordic layout (danish)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Microsoft official website, you can download a keyboard layout creator, to modify or create your own keybindings and keyboard layout.

**Download link here:**
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339

Answer (score 0):

[This is a pic I found on the internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nblN.png)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that image, please note on a US keyboard, they dont have a key besides Z. The shift key is extended instead of an extra key.